# How do I prove :$z\bar{z}=i$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there someone who can prove me that: $z\bar{z}=i$  has no solution in 
 $\mathbb{R}$, where $z$ is complex variable and $\bar{z}$ it conjugate ?

Note: $i$ is imaginary unit.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: actually it even has no solution in C...

Comment: $z\overset { \_  }{ z }$   not equal to $ i $

Comment: $$(a+bi)(a-bi)=?$$

Answer (score 4):

There aren't solutions in any case. If there is such $z$, you can do: $$z\overline{z} = i \implies \overline{z\overline{z}} = \overline{i} \implies \overline{z}z = -i,$$and from this $i = -i$.

Answer (score 2):

$z\overline{z} = |z|^2$ is real, whereas $i$ is imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

The Real numbers, as with any group ( under multiplication) are operationally closed; the product of two Real numbers must be a Real number, and $i$ is not ( I am not?) a Real number.

EDIT: The *non-zero* Real numbers are a group under multiplication.

Comment: but I wondred ur answer in my comment before positing ur answer here

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Any complex number can be written as a real number plus an inmaginary number. Thus, we can write $z=a+ib$, where $a$ and $b$ are real. Then $z\bar z=a^1+ib-ib+b^2=a^2+b^2$, which is real. If $z$ is real, then $b=0$, and you have the same problem.

Comment: I know only that R is a close Ensemble as one reason for no existence of solutions in it